# openapi codegen without fromJson and toJson methods

Tags: java, openapi, openapi-generator, openapi-generator-maven-plugin

I am using openapi-generator-maven-plugin to generate model sources. With my current configuration it generates methods called fromJson and toJson for every model class.

Is there a way to configure the plugin, so it won't generate this Json methods?
I don't need them and they bring dependencies that I don't want in my project.

Here is my current config of the plugin

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
    <artifactId>openapi-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>6.3.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>generate</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <inputSpec>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/api.yaml</inputSpec>
                <generatorName>java</generatorName>
                <language>Java</language>
                <output>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/swagger</output>
                <configOptions>
                    <sourceFolder>src/gen/java/main</sourceFolder>
                    <!-- Add custom annotation for model sources to achieve builder pattern -->
                    <additionalModelTypeAnnotations>@lombok.experimental.SuperBuilder @lombok.AllArgsConstructor</additionalModelTypeAnnotations>
                </configOptions>
                <modelPackage>my.package</modelPackage>
                <!-- Only generate the model since we need it for deserialization -->
                <generateApis>false</generateApis>
                <generateApiDocumentation>false</generateApiDocumentation>
                <generateApiTests>false</generateApiTests>
                <generateModelDocumentation>false</generateModelDocumentation>
                <generateModelTests>false</generateModelTests>
                <generateSupportingFiles>false</generateSupportingFiles>
                <generateModels>true</generateModels>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: You'll probably have to [modify the Mustache templates](https://openapi-generator.tech/docs/templating#modifying-templates) used by the `java` codegen.

Answer (score 3):

The `fromJson` and `toJson` methods are generated when the Java generator library is set to `okhttp-gson` or `retrof`. If not defined, the `openapi-generator` uses `okhttp-gson` by default.

You can view the different JSON processors used by examining the [library config options](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/blob/master/docs/generators/java.md#config-options:%7E:text=true-,library,-library%20template).  The majority of them use Jackson, but the default one uses `gson`.  You can also set your `serializationLibrary` to `jackson`, but this will only effect some library generators; not all.

So, if you set your `library` to whichever is appropriate to your project, the unwanted `toJson` and `fromJson` methods will disappear, as will the unwanted dependencies.